# Does the link with trivial knot group trivial?

Tags: knot-theory, knot-invariants

I know that if a the knot group of a classical knot is isomorphic to the infinite cyclic group, then the knot is unknotted. How about the link, is this result also valid for links. In other words, if the knot group of a link is $\mathbb{Z}^n$, then does this imply that the link is unknotted, where n is the number of components?

Comment: If a link has $n$ components, the 1st homology group of its exterior is $Z^n$. Your question should be about links with the fundamental group of the exterior $\cong F_n$, $n$ is the number of components of the link.

Comment: Oops, thank you. I edited my question.